# How to pass props to a component on clicking button?

Tags: reactjs

I have displayed all the anime images from api, now I want if any anime result is clicked then it should open details for that particular anime. I have created component `Details` where I want to send details of anime. 
how can I send details of anime to the component `Details` ?
Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './CSS/style.css';
import Details from './components/Details';

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([])
  const getUsers = async () =>{
    const response = await fetch('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films')
    setUser(await response.json());
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  const getDetail = (e) =>{
    // what should I write here to pass props on component < Details />
    console.log(e)
  }
  return (   
    <>
      <h2>Anime World</h2>
      <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
        <div className="row text-center">

        {
          user.map((curElem) => {
            return (
            <div className="col-10 col-md-4 mt-5" key={curElem.id}  >
            <div className="card">
              <img src={curElem.image} className="card-img-top imageSize" alt="..."/>
              <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">{curElem.title} </h5>
                <button onClick={getDetail} >Get Detail</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
            )
          })
        }
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Dummy values are given to component `Details` right now, I have to get correct value from props.

```
import React from 'react';
import './details.css';
function Details() {
  return (
    <>
    <h2>Information of Anime</h2>
      <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
        <div className="row text-center">
          <div className="col-10 col-md-8  mx-auto" >
            <div className="card box">
                <img src= '...' className="card-img-top imageSize" alt="..."/>
                <div className="card-body">
                <div className='details'>
                    <h5><span>Title:</span> Title</h5>
                    <h5><span>Original Title:</span> Original Title</h5>
                    <h5><span>Director:</span> Director</h5>
                    <h5><span>Producer:</span> Producer</h5>
                    <h5><span>Release Date:</span> date</h5>
                    <h5><span>Running time:</span> time</h5>
                    <h5><span>Description:</span> <p> Description</p></h5>
                </div>
                    
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Details;
```

Comment: Hey there, I'm a little confused with your code, is component `Details` supposed to be a visual component? If so should it also render in the return HTML?

Comment: yes component is visual component.  I have added component for better understanding.

Comment: not really sure but are you trying to display Details Component when getDetails is clicked ? if yes : you should try something like { myBoolean && <Details items={...theDetails} />} with a boolean changed to true when getDetails is clicked

Comment: Instead of using a button onClick function, since the anime has an id, make the button a router button that takes a user to the details.: use curElem.id to route the user

Comment: @AbdulAzeezOlanrewaju can you please explain me more how to achieve this or can you suggest me any article/blog on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the list you receive from the API is the list of each anime, and when you click you want to render the selected anime using the Details component. If that's the case this is my approach

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './CSS/style.css';
import Details from './components/Details';

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  const [anime, setAnime] = useState(null);

  const getUsers = async () =>{
    const response = await fetch('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films');
    setUser(await response.json());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  const getDetail = (anime) =>{
    setAnime(anime);
  };

  return (   
    <>
      <h2>Anime World</h2>
      <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
        <div className="row text-center">
          {user.map((elem) => (
            <div className="col-10 col-md-4 mt-5" key={curElem.id}>
              <div className="card">
                <img src={elem.image} className="card-img-top imageSize" alt="..."/>
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h5 className="card-title">{elem.title} </h5>
                  <button onClick={() => getDetail(elem)} >Get Detail</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      {anime && <Details {...anime} />}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So basically what I'm doing here is rendering `<Details />` only when an anime element is in state. If it's null it won't render the component.
Secondly I'm spreading the selected element into the `Details` component, so that inside the component you can access each property like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './details.css';
function Details(props) {
  const { title } = props; // each prop is each property of the selected anime

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Information of Anime</h2>
      <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
        <div className="row text-center">
          <div className="col-10 col-md-8  mx-auto" >
            <div className="card box">
                <img src= '...' className="card-img-top imageSize" alt="..."/>
                <div className="card-body">
                <div className='details'>
                    <h5><span>Title:</span> {title}</h5>
                    <h5><span>Original Title:</span> Original Title</h5>
                    <h5><span>Director:</span> Director</h5>
                    <h5><span>Producer:</span> Producer</h5>
                    <h5><span>Release Date:</span> date</h5>
                    <h5><span>Running time:</span> time</h5>
                    <h5><span>Description:</span> <p> Description</p></h5>
                </div>   
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Details;
```

Comment: What if we don't want to show the list container, but to redirect to a Detail page?

Comment: Instead of doing `getDetail` you would create `goToDetail` function where you would do the redirect to the Detail page

Comment: And you could either send the information via cache, or just the id in the url if the api has the possibility to fetch a specific anime